# How do i change the core functionality of yii framework?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

How to change/override the core functionality of yii framework? for instance i need to apply encryption/decryption algorithm on core mysql generator in yii framework instead of encryption/decryption applied on php itself.

we know we can apply encryption technique on php itself, but on converting from old project to new one with same sql format with MYSQL ENC/DEC how to alter/add/change the yii default query builder instead of applying manual query format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can extend desired core class and than rewrite it's methods.

```
//example with CActiveRecord extend
class MyModel extends CActiveRecord()
{
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->is_deleted = 1;
        $this->update(array('is_deleted'));
    }
}

class TableModel extends MyModel
{
}
```

Comment: thank  you for your valuable reply, will try this one. But i am expecting as same as core, what i want is, we know we are using sql manager for core php to build a query instead of manual, here we can add aes_encrypt and decrypt method wherever needed using just an array concept, like wise i need the exact place where the query building in YII framework to add mysql based encryption and decryption techniques.